# python sqllite3 horizontal partitioning by string column

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a 30gb sqllite3 database with 25 million rows. I want to group the table by a string column and create a new table for every group, named after the string and containing all columns.
Is this possible with python and sqllite3? I could process chunks in python, but is there a sql command?

start table: `name = all_entries`

```
a   b   c   d
hi  4   234 lala
bye 7   342 lulu
bye 5   433 abc
bye 4   234 abd
hi  56  435 abc
hi  3   455 a
```

result tables:

`name = bye`

```
a   b   c   d
bye 7   342 lulu
bye 5   433 abc
bye 4   234 abd
```

`name = hi`

```
a   b   c   d
hi  4   234 lala
hi  56  435 abc
hi  3   455 a
```

Comment: You should add example of what you have and what are you trying to achieve. Please take a look at how to provide [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with how to work with sqlite you can take advantage of `pandas` and split your tables into chunks, then push them back to your database.

Here is how you could split the data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['hi', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'hi', 'hi'],
                   'c': [234, 342, 433, 234, 435, 455],
                   'b': [4, 7, 5, 4, 56, 3],
                   'd': ['lala', 'lulu', 'abc', 'abd', 'abc', 'a']})
dfs = {i: df.loc[df['a']==i] for i in df['a'].unique()}
dfs
#{'bye':      a    b  c    d
#          1  bye  7  342  lulu
#          2  bye  5  433   abc
#          3  bye  4  234   abd,
# 'hi':       a   b    c     d
#          0  hi   4  234  lala
#          4  hi  56  435   abc
#          5  hi   3  455     a}
```

Comment: It's possible with pandas, but is there a sql command for that? It's seems to be such a common operation

Comment: @Benni Well once you connect to `sqlite` and execute query you get a `generator` with all the values from your `SELECT`. Now, you can use multiple tools/ways to split the result and `pandas` is one of them.